# UIPinchGestureRecognizer doesn't enter at callback function

Tags: ios, ios5, uigesturerecognizer

I need to set width of some Image on display. Bellow display I need to have some component ( I  am new and I don't know which one) which can fetch **UIPinchGestureRecognizer** so based on that event I need to make width larger or smaller. My question is which component I need to put at the bottom of screen which can fetch  **UIPinchGestureRecognizer** ? Is this possible to test in simulator ?

I added to Controller

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *gestureView;
```

also I have in .xib file UIView. At the bottom of **viewDidLoad** I added code

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
[gestureView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
```

I also in that file have **handlePinch** function but it doesn't enter. Can anybody help ?

Comment: Are you sure `handlePinch` never gets called? Did you put a `NSLog` inside it to make sure?

Comment: @Evan I put breakpoint. One stupid question: is this possible to test on simulator or I need to install app on phone ?

Comment: Is the gestureView connection set up? Replace gestureView with self.view and see if at least the call-back is getting called.

Comment: @Damir If you hold down the Option key in the Simulator, two fingers will appear that you can use to pinch.

Comment: ru enabled gestureView.userIntractionEnabled = YES; for UR View

Answer (score 0):

Is your gestureView hooked up properly in interface builder?  I'm assuming you're using interface builder since it is marked as IBOutlet.

Also, make sure your handlePinch is like this...

```
- (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

}
```

And not like this

```
- (void)handlePinch
{

}
```

The second one will not work in your current implementation.